# How do I get the last element ( the tail) in the list?

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am trying to create Single linked list  but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

*After* inserting elements 5,6,7,2,3,4 the tail should be 4 but I am getting 3 and I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
public void Insert(int x)
{
    Node a = new Node(x);

    if (Head == null)
    {
        Head = Tail = a;
    }
    else
    {
        Tail = Head;
        while (Tail.Next != null)
        {
            Tail = Tail.Next;
        }
        Tail.Next = a;
        a = Tail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just a snippet. (And make the code as readable as possible - compare the version you posted with the version I edited it to. I left the slightly inconsistent use of brace positions, but I was tempted to edit that too.)

Comment: Why do you seek Tail on each insert?

Comment: (1) You already have `Tail` so you don't have to search for it; (2) When inserting value 4, the tail is supposed to be 3. What is the true problem you're experiencing?

Comment: @Fildor because I am dumb ><

Comment: 2 Upvotes say you are not ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set the new value for `Tail` in the negative case:

```
public void Insert(int x)
{
    Node a = new Node(x);

    if (Head == null)
    {
        Head = Tail = a;
    }
    else
    {
        Tail.Next = a;
        Tail = a;
    }
}
```

On a related note, you don't have to *search* for the tail in the negative case, because you already have the `Tail` variable ready.

Comment: Oh gosh I am feeling so dumb thank you for your help really appreciated

Comment: @EndritShabani Hey, your question wasn't downvoted. So it cannot be _that_ dumb! We all know that "cannot see the forest for the trees"  sometimes ...